# Edit & add Administrators permissions without using SUBINACL

Tags: permissions, ntfs, windows-server

I am Server Admin but getting Access denied errors for few folders.

There is a way to use SUBINACL play file.

Is there a way edit & add Administrators permissions without using SUBINACL ?